# Error with a change column mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

what is wrong with this query?

```
ALTER TABLE test_table 
CHANGE text_string text_string VARCHAR(255) 
    COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL 
    COMMENT 'hey here are mysql comments..' ;
```

in PHPMyAdmin it runs fine, but if i execute this query from my PHP class, it returns this:

```
error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<br>' at line 1
```

note there is a `<br>` tag in the mysql error, I assume its from mysql itself as I always use `<br />` . I have searched through my code for a `<br>` too so its not me. Im probably just tired and thats in all mysql errors!

I have been on this now for a while, so why does mysql not like this query? Fresh eyes much appreciated!

---

PHP handler to run the generated query:

```
$q = isset($_POST['q']) ? base64_decode(($_POST['q'])): false;

$db->q($q) or die("error: ".mysql_error());
```

yes, the base64_decode is working right.

---

**$q output:**

decoded query

```
ALTER TABLE sNOWsh_amb_nicks_1st_test_table CHANGE text_string text_string VARCHAR(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'hey here are mysql comments..' ;
```

Comment: not really, its being constructed in a pretty large class file. there are allot of other queries that run through the same class methods and these all work fine. I have added the handler that submits the query, but again its referencing a large class to handle the DB.

Comment: can you show us `$q` output???

Comment: can you try this query by removing this `COMMENT 'hey here are mysql comments..'` from query

Comment: :D @Yogesh Suthar : Thats the part that I am trying to do! This part of my class is to handle changes to a column, including changing the comments

Comment: why so complicated? why you encode and decode the query? whom you want to protect it?

Comment: I'm doing this for a reason. The query is prepared on a different page and is submitted to be executed on a submit page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I decode that bas64 string, it ends with `;<br />`. If you're using PHP to display it, make sure you use `htmlentities`, otherwise the browser will translate the `<br />` to a newline and you won't see it.

You need to look at the application that's sending the POST data. It looks like it's constructing HTML from its input, so newlines are being converted to `<br />`.

Comment: OH I got so excited then! You were right, a <br> was being created in my class with nl2br() - I needed it for some output..
Fixed that, the base64 looks good (see update in question) but... still getting the same error...

Comment: Are you sure that's the complete base64 string? It doesn't end with `=`. The only other place I think the problem could be is in your class that performs the query.

Comment: oh, wait up! looks I got it! You were right, it was the class adding a <br />! Many Thanks!